# Make an ajax call from JavaScript to C# controller in a different folder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

**Update Note at the bottom of question**

I am having issues making an AJAX call from JavaScript to the C# Controller. I am pretty sure that my issue is the connection url of my AJAX call on the javascript file. If the connection url is not the issue, then I think it might be something in my C# controller. I know jQuery is loaded properly since I was able to console log information before the AJAX call in the RunDemo function.

Here is an explanation of what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a simple html page with one button. On button click, I need to make an ajax call to my c# controller and retrieve a string. On AJAX success I would then alert on the html page to the user the messages retrieved from the C# controller. Here is a picture of my "TheDemo" repository:

[image]

Here is my "Index" html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-container">
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <button type="button" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the "demo.js" javascript file:

```
//Function makes an ajax to the controller
function RunDemo(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Demo/RunDemo',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (retData)
        {
            console.log(retData);
            alert(retData.Message);
        },
        error: function (retData)
        {
            console.log(retData);
        }
    });
}

//Event handles the "Submit" button
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitButton", function () {
    RunDemo()
});
```

Here is the "DemoController.cs" C# file:

```
using System;

class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RunDemo()
    {
        object obj = new { Message = "Return From Controller" };
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }   
}
```

Here is an image of my error in the Google Chrome console:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have fixed the ajax connection url. It still does not work, I have updated the image of the Google Chrome console.

**UPDATE 2:**

It has been brought to my attention that it could be the way I am opening the file. At the moment, I am opening the html page with Google Chrome inspector. I am not "running" a process in Visual Studio code. Do I need to host the C# Controller in something?

Thanks!

Comment: The url's for controllers are defined by the routing, not by the name.  The default routing uses the name, so it may look like it's by the name, but you can change the routing without changing the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX URL is relative to your HTML file, which is itself on your local disk. Therefore, it is not going to your controller, which is running on `localhost` presumably, but is going to `file:///Demo/RunDemo` as per the error message.

AJAX requests are better debugged via the Network tab of your browser development tools.

tl;dr -- Invoke your page via the URL as hosted by your ASP.NET app. It should be along the lines of `http://localhost/View/index.html`.

Comment: Oh that might be the issue. I am opening the html file, by going "Open With Google Chrome",I am not "running anything" Do I need to do something different?

Comment: Well, you need to be running your ASP.NET MVC application for it to respond to your AJAX requests.

Comment: Oh I think that might be the issue! I thought I could just open the html file by itself. Thanks for the help! I cannot make any more changes at the moment. But I will report back in about 4 hours. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The url you specified for ajax call is not correct. in ASP.NET mvc we specify just the controller name without the controller postfix and the format of the url also not correct. try the following for url:

```
url: '/Demo/RunDemo'
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! Unfortunately it did not quite work, I have updated the original question with the new console error and added something else I did not mention originally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fix your ajax file

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Demo/RunDemo',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (retData)
        {
            console.log(retData);
            alert(retData.Message);
        },
        error: function (retData)
        {
            console.log(retData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply! It did not quite work, I have updated the original question with the new console error and added something else I did not mention originally. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is not with the AJAX call but with the CORS permission at the back-end for the security of the system with cross origin resource sharing. you see even though it's allow resource on same URL but your browser blocks the all the resources from different URL.

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.Http.Cors;
    class DemoController : Controller
    {
      [EnableCors(origins: "http://yourlocalhost:", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
      [HttpPost]
      public JsonResult RunDemo()
    {
        object obj = new { Message = "Return From Controller" };
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }   
}
```

Try to look into this document if above code does not help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api